# How to run service not on main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, android-service

I'm trying to launch `service` and then open `socket` to have connection with server.

On button click I create new `Thread` and then start service.

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            mIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConnectonService.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("KEY1", "Value used by the service");
            context.startService(mIntent);
        }
    };
t.start();
```

Then on `service`, I try to open `socket` and have connection with server

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO do something useful


    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        message = scanner.nextLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

But when I call it, I have **error**

```
08-30 08:56:49.268: E/AndroidRuntime(3751): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.testofconnection.ConnectonService@40ef02a8 with Intent { cmp=com.example.testofconnection/.ConnectonService (has extras) }: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException*
```

I think problem is that `service` is on `main thread`, but I can't find how should I start service on new (independend) thread to keep `connection alive`?

Comment: I need to keep connection with server alive. AsyncTask only opens connection, sends some request, got some response and closes, so I found that with service I can implement it

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html. check the topic under extending service class

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use IntentService for this. Just launch it normally with an Intent from the main thread. `onHandleIntent()` method gets executed in background thread. Put your socket-code in there. Here is an example code.

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // this method is called in background thread
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }    
}
```

In your activity you start the service as following.

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class));
```

If you need a long-lasting service, you can create a normal service and start a thread there. Here is an example. Make sure you launch it as "foreground" service. This will allow service to run longer without been killed by Android.

```
public class MyAsyncService extends Service {

    private AtomicBoolean working = new AtomicBoolean(true)

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(working.get()) {
                // put your socket-code here
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // start new thread and you your work there
        new Thread(runnable).start();

        // prepare a notification for user and start service foreground
        Notification notification = ...
        // this will ensure your service won't be killed by Android
        startForeground(R.id.notification, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public onDestroy() {
        working.set(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: But I read that IntentService is only for one time task. I should keep connection alive through socket, send some request to the server, recieve response and listen to the server commands. This is quite difficult long term task. Can I use IntentService to implement it?

Comment: @Ragaisis You should better use normal service with a thread. I updated my answer. Does this help?

Comment: I totally agree with this answer but I have one question that can we not go ahead and use a thread directly instead of using it inside service? I mean what makes it different.?

Comment: Why not use `onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` ?

Answer (score 6):

Move this code to your thread:

```
try {
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
    message = scanner.nextLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Just as an example (I'm not sure it this fits to your task):

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                message = scanner.nextLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConnectonService.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("KEY1", "Value used by the service");
            context.startService(mIntent);
        }
    };
t.start();
```

You should know that a service is running on the UI thread, so you got this error. Check [this nice site](http://techtej.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html) for more information about various threading approaches in Android.

Comment: Putting startService in new Thread has no effect. Service still started on main thread. Also the site you linked say so.

Comment: Services run on the UI thread, yes - however, in the example above, the thread `t` is only initiated _from_ a service and so its code is running in this, separate thread, I'm pretty sure. Note: don't start the thread with `run()` but with `start()`!

Comment: Because a service has no UI to be blocked, is it OK to run things in UI/main thread in Android Service?