# Thread reacting to signal 3

Tags: java, android

I want to wait for a specific time to execute a function but I get the

> Error:
>   Thread[2,tid=3699,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa9f2c500,peer=0x36c090a0,"Signal
>   Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

during the "sleepUntil" function:

```
    try {
        TimeInMillis = getTimeInMillis();
        currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        sleepUntil(TimeInMillis);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Function to calculate time in milliseconds:

```
    public long getTimeInMillis(){
    long TimeInMillis = 0;
    Date date = new Date();
    currentDate = dateformatter.format(date);
    updateTime = currentDate + " " + updateTime;
    try {
        parseTime = formatter.parse(updateTime);
        TimeInMillis = parseTime.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(TimeInMillis);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    return TimeInMillis;
}
```

Function to wait:

```
public static void sleepUntil(long date) throws InterruptedException {
    //Thread.sleep(Math.max(date - System.currentTimeMillis(),0));
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(Math.max(date-System.currentTimeMillis(),0));
```

Comment: You should not use a thread on the main thread(UI thread), you can use handler to implement your logic.

Comment: I'm using this is a Service class, so i should call the Service with a handler?

Comment: if you want to start a service after a wait then you can do that. but if you want to use sleep then you should use different thread then main.

Comment: I think you miss understood me i dont want to wait and then start the Service. My Service Needs to wait until a specifc time to exectute another function and for that i am using the above Code. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong and why i get this error. Also in a Code example if possible.

Comment: You are getting this error because service runs on main thread and you are trying to pause main thread using sleep, try implementing your logic using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18526280/5901903
and you can use `SystemClock.sleep(millis)` for wait

Comment: Thank you for you help i will this now :)

Comment: Thank you once more it worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not use a thread on the main thread(UI thread).
You are getting this error because service runs on main thread and you are trying to pause main thread using sleep, try implementing your logic using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18526280/5901903) and you can use `SystemClock.sleep(millis)` for wait